# Would like this function to return when a string matches a value in an object partially or completely

Tags: javascript, filtering, lodash

I'm trying to filter using javascript and lodash. The search is performed using an input field and I want this function to return when `this.props.search` matches a value in the `file` object partially or completely. Without using the object's key names.

```
let files = [{
    'id': '00001',
    'fileName' : 'Test01.test',
    'size': 105,
    'uploadDate' : '2016-02-12',
    'permissions' : 'Private'
}, {
    'id': '00002',
    'fileName' : 'Test02.test',
    'size': 111,
    'uploadDate' : '2016-02-10',
    'permissions' : 'Private'
}, {
    'id': '00003',
    'fileName' : 'Test03.test',
    'size': 55,
    'uploadDate' : '2016-02-06',
    'permissions' : 'Shared'
}];

let filteredFiles = files.filter((file) => {
    return _.includes(file, this.props.search);
});
```

But using the function it will only work when it matches the string completetly. What am I doing wrong? I am open to not using lodash also if there's a suggestion.

**UPDATE:**

I end up using the following:

```
   let filteredFiles = this.props.files.filter((file) => {
        for (let prop in file) {
            let string = String(file[prop]).toLowerCase();
            if (string.indexOf(this.props.search.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you want to apply the `includes()` function to each property value (or more accurately, till a match is found), not the object itself.

Try this:

```
let filteredFiles = files.filter((file) => {
     return _.some(file, _.partial(_.includes, _, this.props.search, 0));
});
```

Comment: it returns an empty array.

Comment: _.partial works but only when using the complete string, not partially. @Amit

Comment: @Gab - `partialRight` was a bad call, and I'm not even 100% certain this works now (can't run the code right now), but feel free to correct me if required.

Comment: @Gab - while I appreciate the "accepted answer" flag, voting is much more useful (for the community as a whole, and personally for me as well). It'd be nice if you upvoted the useful answer**s** you received. Thanks!

Comment: Done ... I end up using the other answer's code because I had to add .toLowerCase on the search and values to make it work correctly

Comment: @Gab - in that case I would suggest using a RegExp for testing. It will be easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through all the properties and check if your search value is in any of the properties.

```
let filteredFiles = files.filter((file) => {
    for (var prop in file) {
       var val = file[prop];
       if (val === this.props.search || String(val).includes(this.prop.search)) {
           return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
});
```

Or here's a version that is a little more lodash like, but still VanillaJS, inspired by Amit's answer.

```js
"use strict";
function filter(files, value) {
  return files.filter(file => {
    return Object.keys(file).some(key => {
      return file[key] === value || String(file[key]).includes(value);
    });
  });
}



let files = [{
  'id': '00001',
  'fileName': 'Test01.test',
  'size': 105,
  'uploadDate': '2016-02-12',
  'permissions': 'Private'
}, {
  'id': '00002',
  'fileName': 'Test02.test',
  'size': 111,
  'uploadDate': '2016-02-10',
  'permissions': 'Private'
}, {
  'id': '00003',
  'fileName': 'Test03.test',
  'size': 55,
  'uploadDate': '2016-02-06',
  'permissions': 'Shared'
}];


document.write('Filtering by Pri: ' + filter(files, 'Pri').length + ' matches<br/>');
document.write('Filtering by 105: ' + filter(files, '105').length + ' matches<br/>');
```

Comment: That's OK for VanillaJS, but the question is specifically about lodash, and if that's already available *not* using its powers is wrong.

Comment: @Amit, from the OP `I am open to not using lodash also if there's a suggestion.` To me this is clearer than what did with lodash, unless you're very familiar with it.

Comment: Fair enough (though that was edited-in later, so excuse me for not noticing). How is that clearer though? (And BTW, use [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) instead of `indexOf() >= 0`)

Comment: @Amit No, I have never been a fan of lodash or the other utility libraries. I'll keep my answer to VanillaJS. I am not going to argue with you about clarity, I find it easier to follow each step of the code.

Comment: I'm not suggesting to use anything but VanillaJS. I rarely use other libraries myself.

Comment: I wonder why you bother do the strict equality first. Is that for optimization?

Comment: @Amit because I didn't want it to match if you ask for 27 and it has a 275, but you've uncovered a bug. In any case, the OP can figure out the exact matching strategy

Answer (score 0):

Because you are passing an object as the first parameter to `_.includes`, it is checking if any of the values stored in `file` have the exact value of `this.props.search`. If you want to see if a particular field matches at all, you should pass that field name, then it will search for a string part rather than a complete match. For instance:

```
let filteredFiles = files.filter((file) => {
   return _.includes(file.fileName, this.props.search);
});
```

Comment: What I would like to search all fields? updated my question.